# Does Tegmark's Mathematical Universe Hypothesis require instantiation/substrate/implementation?

Tags: cosmology, universe, mathematics, theory-of-everything

Max Tegmark's [Mathematical Universe Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Mathematical_Universe) appears to be a "radical Platonist" theory, arguing that mathematical structures form the basis of the universe/reality.

One thing that's not clear to me is: **does Tegmark argue that the mathematical structures are alone sufficient to result in the universe we observe, or do they require some sort of [substrate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substrate) in which those structures are implemented/instantiated? If so, what does he say about the substrate?**

For example, a circle might be described by a relationship like:

$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$

However, all observable circles always appear to be coupled with a substrate:

- A drawn circle is implemented in variation of density of particles of ink on paper
- Circle in the sand: from variation in sand depth
- Outline of the moon: variation of light intensity

Does Tegmark argue that the substrate is a mathematical structure, and we are directly observing variations within it when we look at the world?

Comment: As far as I know, he is adopting the "everything is math and that's it" approach. No substrate.  I am open to correction of course.

Comment: Or one could say that there is a substrate which is itself part of the maths (that's how I understood the book).

Comment: Would [philosophy.SE] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I thought that since Tegmark is a physicist, more people here would be familiar with his theory and be more likely to know the answer to the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is about philosophy, not physics. It might be on-topic at [philosophy.SE].